# C++ template: <class> does not name a type

Tags: c++, templates

Newbie to C++ so please forgive me. I'm trying to write a simple template class to implement the Stack data structure functionality. I've read through this question to understand how template declaration and implementation works: [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file). But I would like to use the solution where class declaration and implementation are separate (not defined inline in .h).

MyStack.h:

```
#include "StackNode.h"
#include "MyStack.tpp"

template <typename T>
class MyStack
{
private:
    StackNode<T> *top;

public:
    MyStack();
    virtual ~MyStack();
};
```

MyStack.tpp:

```
#include "MyStack.h"

template <typename T>
MyStack<T>::MyStack()
:   top(nullptr)
{

}

template <typename T>
MyStack<T>::~MyStack()
{
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "MyStack.h"

int main() {

    MyStack<int> myStack;

    return 0;
}
```

However compiling the above gives this error:

```
../src/MyStack.tpp:11:1: error: 'MyStack' does not name a type
../src/MyStack.tpp:18:1: error: 'MyStack' does not name a type
```

I know I'm missing something, but don't understand what. Thanks!

Comment: You are including the .tpp file *before* the class is declared. You should have this include at the end of the header. And not include MyStack.h again.

Comment: Oh wow! thanks! D'oh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are including the `.tpp` file, which contains the class method definitions, before the class has actually been declared yet.  You need to move that `#include` statement below the class declaration instead.

Also, the `.tpp` file should not be `#include`'ing the `.h` file that originally `#include`'d it.  In fact, that won't work correctly since your `.h` file is missing header guards to prevent multiple inclusions within the same translation unit (ie, `main.cpp` in this case).  So, you would end up with `MyStack.h` which includes `MyStack.tpp` which includes `MyStack.h` again, which causes an error when it tries to re-declare things that are already declared.  Always declare a header guard in your `.h` files.

Try this instead:

MyStack.h:

```
#ifndef MyStack_H
#define MyStack_H

#include "StackNode.h"

template <typename T>
class MyStack
{
private:
    StackNode<T> *top;

public:
    MyStack();
    virtual ~MyStack();
};

#include "MyStack.tpp"

#endif
```

MyStack.tpp:

```
template <typename T>
MyStack<T>::MyStack()
:   top(nullptr)
{

}

template <typename T>
MyStack<T>::~MyStack()
{
}
```